# Calculating angle between two vectors in GLSL

Tags: opengl, geometry, glsl

I'm working in GLSL, and need to calculate the angle between two 2D vectors fast and efficiently.

Given two vec2 vectors, for instance (30, 20) and (50, 50), I need to calculate the angle between them.

I'm currently using

```
acos(dot(vector1, vector2));
```

Although this doesn't seem to be giving me the angle correctly. Am I doing something wrong, or is this the right function to be using?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A vector dot product will compute the cosine of the angle between two vectors, [*scaled by the length of both vectors*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition). If you want to get just the angle, you must normalize both vectors before doing the dot product.

Answer (score 8):

The dot product alone will give you some very rough information about the angle between two vectors, even if they're not unit vectors:

- If the dot product is 0, the vectors are 90 degrees apart (orthogonal or perpendicular).
- If the dot product is less than 0, the vectors are more than 90 degrees apart.
- If the dot product is greater than 0, the vectors are less than 90 degrees apart.

Comment: That's very helpful!